# how to check if two variable are same or not by using if or statement

Tags: python, django, if-statement

in the below code ,  am trying to check if posted content have any keyword as "whatis" or "what" , everything works , but when I put if statement it show syntax error

```
def addsearch(request):
    addsearch = request.POST.get('searchcontent')
    wordlist = re.sub("[^\w]", " ", addsearch).split()


    s = ''.join(wordlist)
    question = re.findall('whatis', s)[0]

    q = ''.join(wordlist)
    question1 = re.findall('what', q)[0]

    q1 = "what" , q2 ="whatis"
    if question == q2 or question1 == q1
        abc = "this is a question"

    return render(request, 'searchme.html', {"addsearch": addsearch, "splitcontent":wordlist,"question":question,"abc":abc})
```

Comment: Please include the error you're getting

Comment: You need a column after the if statement: `if question == q2 or question1 == q1:`

Comment: `q1 = "what" , q2 ="whatis"` is a syntax error.  Put those two statements on separate lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 errors in your code.

The first is the variables declaration, change this:

```
q1 = "what" , q2 = "whatis"
```

to this:

```
q1 = "what"
q2 = "whatis"
```

The second one is the if statement where you need to write `:` at the end:

```
if question == q2 or question1 == q1:
        abc = "this is a question"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error because you didn't include a colon in your if statement.

change:

```
if question == q2 or question1 == q1
            abc = "this is a question"
```

to this:

```
if question == q2 or question1 == q1:
            abc = "this is a question"
```

Comment: still its show error .. SyntaxError: can't assign to literal